# Can I filter my results with a WHERE clause based on the result from a subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

This is my current mysql query.

```
    SELECT t.id, t.customer, t.indicator_tag, t.indicator_manu, t.indicator_model, t.created_at, t.updated_at, 
    ( SELECT status FROM events WHERE ticket_id = t.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS status, 
    ( SELECT CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) FROM users WHERE id = t.created_by ) AS created_by, 
    ( SELECT CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) FROM users WHERE id = t.updated_by ) AS updated_by 
    FROM tickets t 
    WHERE status = 'Pending' OR status = 'Diagnosed' OR status = 'Repaired' 
    ORDER BY t.customer ASC, status ASC, t.indicator_tag ASC;
```

The WHERE clause in the above statement does not throw any errors, but it also does not filter anything either.  I am still fairly new to SQL so I haven't delved too deeply into JOINS yet.  I should also note that the events table will have multiple events for each ticket, and that the sub-query on line 2 will just grab the newest one.  Is there a way to filter the results based on data from another table but while only grabbing the newest event for each ticket?

To put it another way: 
TABLE tickets HAS MANY events 
events BELONG to ticket

[HTML Output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvcPn.png)

The example above will show the output that I get.  Note that it shows merely the newest status rather than all of the events like it would on the single ticket page.  If I could provide more information I would be happy to oblige.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT t.id, t.customer, t.indicator_tag, t.indicator_manu, t.indicator_model, t.created_at, t.updated_at, 
    ( SELECT status FROM events WHERE ticket_id = t.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS status, 
    ( SELECT CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) FROM users WHERE id = t.created_by ) AS created_by, 
    ( SELECT CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) FROM users WHERE id = t.updated_by ) AS updated_by 
FROM tickets t 
HAVING status = 'Pending' OR status = 'Diagnosed' OR status = 'Repaired' 
ORDER BY t.customer ASC, status ASC, t.indicator_tag ASC;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> A HAVING clause can refer to any column or **alias** named in a select_expr in the SELECT list or in outer subqueries.